# Chef Vault Item was not encrypted with your public key

Tags: chef-infra

Trying to store encrypted credentials for user creation Chef Vault and then deploy the cookbook to the node I want the user created on.

Using Chef version 12.13.37

Using chef-vault cookbook 2.1.1

Initially created the vault with

```
knife vault create ftp users \ '{"user":"password"}' \ --search 'name:my_node_name' \ --admins bk0155 \ --mode client
```

Output of `knife vault show ftp users` gives

```
id:             users
user: password
```

My recipe has this in it:

```
include_recipe 'chef-vault'
vault = ChefVault::Item.load("ftp", "users")
user 'testuser' do
      comment 'Test User Account'
      home '/home/testuser'
      shell '/sbin/bash'
      group 'testusers'
      password vault['user']
end
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
 ChefVault::Exceptions::SecretDecryption
 ---------------------------------------
 ftp/users is not encrypted with your public key.  Contact an administrator of the vault item to encrypt for you!

 Cookbook Trace:
 ---------------
 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ftp_test/recipes/default.rb:10:in 
 `from_file'


/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/compat_resource/files/lib/chef_compat/monkeypatches/chef/run_context.rb:347:in `load_recipe'

  Relevant File Content:
  ----------------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ftp_test/recipes/default.rb:

    3:  # Recipe:: default
    4:  #
    5:  # Copyright:: 2017, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.
    6:  #
    7:
    8:  include_recipe 'chef-vault'
    9:
   10>> vault = ChefVault::Item.load("ftp", "users")
   11:
```

I've tried doing 
`knife update ftp users -S 'name:my_node_name' -M client` to update but that doesn't seem to help

Doing a `knife data bag show ftp users_keys` gives:

```
WARNING: Unencrypted data bag detected, ignoring any provided secret options.
admins:
  bk0155
  my_node_name
my_node_name: fqkwg0098mpbDiJKFCsBEoMLiyN0kZLksiZpWwoxepr6lUgBMFGkJvSpkoGf
3ZwZt8PG2keNe9RYQ93rvgRBKGhLwP46lvDMLO78CEBPfSV5S2mYoe7B7mBb
NFhHPmWkXX2IhaL6TkLvvjATVqBEuUbeqtDb7HO5XOSTuBHacovQxEJerHmA
dXWBsPgs/GPnsu8xK3BNLHjvyVJ3ovaYkvCTxdFTWvDfb8184jC9rJX882Op
XCeGhZ3I5BPXDmNi5XW7EAPgjtbqgxIGPZwYHrrEcZji4TMKxnc6O5+9rPB/
/j4mM/QEL5zGtTeeluzmX+wSE605p9KwGAqsLpUn/g==

clients:                  my_node_name
id:                       users_keys
bk0155:                 mDsML41veFJclX0yXVMqYGvW52uRnZRtQTrRl1XTddgUJc0N9RR1qnyk0gxC
07jKkN+AsdkFuMoOGr7UcUCo/1MEsL125CvsSevOGOF9QMvUk67xw8Q+OlP0
4vqmvJNyaxeXxVV7FOVJSTC2ytovStD2WaSshZutNhG+EgIZ0zSOivHHryW+
aFyClqjVIA3Sm7ITuEyheqBJZZntpHhK1a4Gwk1V3T9aJZ3OT5vvFtNzppnx
CerZvQjPdthwmrqbKfMmYG3KmsPUPEMsAHxK8ryw8Sntu/MYechWzUTGYDii
gcuhehwUCgb+6LAM66ygiIqxcpZ3qg2ddcSUbo5V0g==

search_query:             name:my_node_name
```

I have also tried `knife vault rotate keys` and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance your node key changed, you should run `knife vault refresh ftp users_keys`, with `-M client` if you do not set this in knife.rb. If it does not work, try dropping the whole vault and creating it from scratch, but `refresh` should be sufficient.

[`update` is for updating the content of the vault, `rotate` is for rotating shared key not client's keys](https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/master/KNIFE_EXAMPLES.md).

Comment: 1. Unfortunately `refresh` didn't change the status of the decryption process. Results in same error.
2. Recreating the vault results in the same error.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the credentials using

```
knife data bag show VAULT ITEM_keys [--user=USER]
# keep track of --admins
knife data bag delete VAULT ITEM_keys [-C CLIENT] [--user=USER] -y
knife data bag delete VAULT ITEM [-C CLIENT] [--user=USER] -y
```

Now you are good to create however you may want to supply `[--admins=]`